# Set all paths properly, still get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, path, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I know it´s a common question in several settings, but I still couldn´t fix it:

when I want to run a main from a formerly well working project, I always get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ProjectMain Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ProjectMain
```

I have set the path and the Classpath correctly ( I guess), the compiler is running properly.
I just could set the path to the JRE to the .exe file, don't get it separately.

Java version  "17.0.3.1" 2022-04-22 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3.1+2-LTS-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3.1+2-LTS-6, mixed mode, sharing)
Any ideas what goes wrong?

Comment: How are you running it? What's the directory structure? Where are you running it from?

Comment: Oh, from eclipse. It used to work for months, but then I installed an older version of Java recently to get STS (Spring Tool Suite) running, thought an older version was required.. since then I´m in trouble!

Comment: Weird thing is that spring based programs in the same eclipse workspace run properly!

Comment: If you are facing the same problem: try setting an alternate JRE in the run configuration settings in your IDE! This worked for me  :)